# Issue with saving SSIS package in SQL Server (SSMS 2017)

Tags: import, ssis, ssms

I am using the import and export wizard to import a text file (flat file source) into SQL. As of yet, I have been going to the advanced menu and manually editing the column names and data types (24 in total). I am hoping to save the SSIS package and therefore save the import steps and therefore not have to do this manual adjustment every time that I import this well. I have 64 more to go.

I select "Save SSIS Package" and then Next. However, at this point there is a dropdown titled, "Packaage Protection level". The options are

1. do not save sensitive data
2. encrypt sensitive data with user key
3. encrypt sensitive data with password
4. encrypt all data with user key
5. encrypt alle data with password
6. rely on server storage and roles for access control.

From there, it wants a name and description. I give it a generic title. The resulting error is "the attempted operation is not supported with this database version".

First question: Am I incorrect in thinking that this operation would save the import steps and lend some automation to my processing?

Second question: Does the package protection level affect the operation being successful or not?

Comment: What version and edition of SQL Server are you creating this package against? `SELECT @@VERSION`

Comment: Yes, this will save your steps and lend some automation to package creation.  No, the protection level is not likely related to that error.  The protection level defines how credentials are stored in the package.  Typically, we use option 1 which does not save them and we configure them at runtime with environments.  Please let us know the version and any further messages that were returned with the error

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545)  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 6.3 <X64> (Build 15063: )

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using Express Edition. That edition does not support saving SSIS packages. It only supports the immediate execution of a package. 
Developer/Standard/Enterprise editions support saving SSIS packages from the Import/Export wizard

Answer (score 1):

When you try to save the SSIS package to the SQL Server, the package is stored in the `msdb.sysssispackages` table. However, SQL Server 2016 Express Edition doesn't support SSIS, so you're not able to save the package to the server.

Try saving it to the File System instead.